# What is the meaning of "baptism by fire"?

Tags: exegesis, baptism, pneumatology, gospel-of-luke, john-the-baptist

We all know what water baptism and baptism by the Holy Spirit are. But what does John the Baptist mean by, "He will baptize you with the Holy Spirit and **FIRE**" in Luke 3:16:

> John answered and said to them all, "As for me, I baptize you with water; but One is coming who is mightier than I, and I am not fit to untie the thong of His sandals; He will baptize you with the Holy Spirit and **fire**." (emphasis added)

Is there a generally-accepted interpretation of what *fire* means in this context; or can there be a quick overview of the most-accepted understandings?

Comment: This is an excellent question and worthy of remaining open due to the fact as stated below there are scriptures to support the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This answer is based on the Christian theology of [Emanuel Swedenborg](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Emanuel_Swedenborg) (1688-1772), and his spiritual mode of interpreting the Bible. It represents the view on this subject of the "New Church" or "Swedenborgian" denominations that accept Swedenborg's theology.

The question is based on Luke 3:16-17:

> John answered all of them by saying, "I baptize you with water; but one who is more powerful than I is coming; I am not worthy to untie the thong of his sandals. He will baptize you with the Holy Spirit and fire. His winnowing fork is in his hand, to clear his threshing floor and to gather the wheat into his granary; but the chaff he will burn with unquenchable fire."

There are four key elements here related to the question that need to be explained and understood:

1. Baptism
2. Baptism with *water*
3. Baptism with *the Holy Spirit*
4. Baptism with *fire*

### Baptism

In the New Testament, baptism was practiced by John the Baptist and Jesus' disciples, and commanded by Jesus himself (see [Matthew 28:16-20](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Matthew%2028%3A16-20&version=NRSV)) as a permanent ritual, or sacrament, that would introduce people into the Christian church. Those who are baptized are considered Christians, whether baptized as infants or as adults.

Baptism itself is a ritual of *cleansing.* As originally practiced, it involved being fully immersed in flowing water such as the Jordan River.

In non-religious terms, baptism is a bath. The purpose of a bath physically is to clean the body of dirt and impurities.

Spiritually, therefore, baptism represents the cleansing of a person from evil, falsity, and sin. This is the first step in the process of being born again, or spiritual rebirth.

That is why baptism is presented in the New Testament as "the baptism of repentance for the forgiveness of sins" (see [Matthew 3:11; Mark 1:4; Luke 3:3; Acts 2:38, 13:24, 19:4](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Matthew%203%3A11%3B%20Mark%201%3A4%3B%20Luke%203%3A3%3B%20Acts%202%3A38%2C%2013%3A24%2C%2019%3A4&version=NRSV)). Baptism is not about mere *physical* cleansing; it is a ritual symbolic of the *spiritual* cleansing of repentance from our sins, and thereby accepting God's forgiveness, entering into the Christian religion, and being born again as a new creation in Christ (see [2 Corinthians 5:17](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=2%20Corinthians%205:17&version=NRSV)).

In Christianity, baptism takes the place of all the Old Testament rituals of washing and purification.

Luke 3:16 and [Matthew 3:11](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Matthew%203%3A11&version=NRSV) speak of three forms of baptism:

- with water
- with the Holy Spirit
- with fire

Since baptism in general represents a cleansing of Christian believers from evil, falsity, and sin, each of these forms of baptism represent a cleansing at a different level of a Christian's life.

### Baptism with *water*

In Matthew 3:11, John the Baptist says:

> I baptize you with water for repentance.

In the Bible, water is often used as a symbol of truth. For example, Deuteronomy 32:2 reads:

```
May my teaching drop like the rain,
    my speech condense like the dew;
like gentle rain on grass,
    like showers on new growth.
```

Baptism with water, then, represents allowing our lives to be cleansed by the *truth* of Jesus' teaching.

But more specifically, the baptism of water performed by John the Baptist was a baptism of repentance from evil, falsity, and sin in a person's *outward behavior.*

When the people being baptized by John asked him what they must do, he told them that they must stop *acting* wrongly, and start *acting* rightly:

> "What should we do then?" the crowd asked.
>
> John answered, "Anyone who has two shirts should share with the one who has none, and anyone who has food should do the same."
>
> Even tax collectors came to be baptized. "Teacher," they asked, "what should we do?"
>
> "Don't collect any more than you are required to," he told them.
>
> Then some soldiers asked him, "And what should we do?"
>
> He replied, "Don't extort money and don't accuse people falsely—be content with your pay." (Luke 3:10-14)

In fact, John's imprisonment and later execution by Herod was a result of his rebuking Herod for his *behavior:*

> But when John rebuked Herod the tetrarch because of his marriage to Herodias, his brother's wife, and all the other evil things he had done, Herod added this to them all: He locked John up in prison. (Luke 3:19-20)

The first baptism, then, baptism by *water,* represents the cleansing of our *outward actions,* and our *speech,* from evil, falsity, and sin.

The first step in Christian life and rebirth is to stop speaking falsehoods and lies, and stop doing things that are evil and sinful. This is the "baptism of water for repentance" practiced by John the Baptist and by the disciples of Jesus.

But there are two further, and deeper, forms of baptism. John the Baptist said that Jesus Christ (the "one more powerful than I" who "is coming") "will baptize you with the Holy Spirit and fire."

### Baptism with *the Holy Spirit*

The Holy Spirit, like water, refers to *truth.* But it is truth of a deeper kind. It is not *outward* truth, but "the *spirit* of truth":

> When the Spirit of truth comes, he will guide you into all the truth; for he will not speak on his own, but will speak whatever he hears, and he will declare to you the things that are to come. (John 16:13, and see also [John 14:16-17, 15:26](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=John%2014%3A16-17%2C%2015%3A26&version=NRSV))

Baptism with the Holy Spirit, then, is the next step beyond the cleansing of our outward life through repenting from sin and instead speaking and acting with kindness and truth. Baptism with the Holy Spirit is the cleansing of our *inward* self, and specifically of our *thoughts and beliefs.*

The truth that does this is not the outward truth of right *behavior* represented by the baptism of water performed by John the Baptist, but the deeper *spiritual and divine* truth that cleanses our mind and spirit from falsity and error.

When we are baptized with the Holy Spirit, we follow the guidance of the Holy Spirit into all the truth. We allow the Holy Spirit to re-form our thinking, our faith, our beliefs. The result of baptism with the Holy Spirit is that our mind is enlightened, and we walk in the light of God's spiritual truth.

### Baptism with *fire*

The third and final form of baptism mentioned in Matthew 3:11 and Luke 3:16 is *baptism with fire.*

Since ancient times, in all cultures, *fire* with its warmth has been seen as a symbol of *love.* In the ancient love poem called "The Song of Solomon," 8:6, we read:

```
Set me as a seal upon your heart,
    as a seal upon your arm;
for love is strong as death,
    passion fierce as the grave.
Its flashes are flashes of fire,
    a raging flame.
```

And when Solomon dedicated the first temple, and the people saw fire from the Lord descending over it, they instinctively recognized that it represented the Lord's *love* for them:

> When all the people of Israel saw the *fire* come down and the glory of the Lord on the temple, they bowed down on the pavement with their faces to the ground, and worshiped and gave thanks to the Lord, saying, "For he is good, for *his steadfast love* endures forever." (2 Chronicles 7:3, italics added)

When Jesus Christ baptizes us with *the Holy Spirit,* it is a baptism with spiritual and divine *truth.*

When Jesus Christ baptizes us with *fire,* it is a baptism with spiritual and divine *love.*

Having had our outward behavior cleansed with the baptism of water, and our mind cleansed with the spirit of truth, the third baptism is to have our heart cleansed with the baptism of the fire of God's *love.*

We humans are a mixture of good and evil loves and motives. Some of the things we want are good. We may enjoy doing a kind deed for a fellow human being in need. But some of the things we want are bad. We may enjoy cussing out someone who has crossed us.

Perhaps through the power of Christ working in our lives we have been able to reform our behavior so that we no longer cuss people out, lie, steal, and so on. Perhaps we even know in our mind that these things are *wrong,* and we therefore discipline ourselves not to act on them even when we desperately *want* to.

In the final baptism, the baptism with *fire,* Jesus Christ cleanses our *hearts,* meaning our loves, desires, and motives, so that we no longer even *want* those evil things. We no longer *have* those evil and selfish impulses. Or if we ever do, instead of feeling the old pleasure at the thought of slugging someone who's insulted us, we find the very thought of doing such a thing intensely distressing and unpleasant.

*Baptism with fire* is the cleansing of our loves, desires, and motives from all evil, selfish, and greedy impulses, and from the pleasure we used to get from nursing and indulging in those evil desires.

#### The intense process of purification by fire

This does not happen easily.

It is no accident that "trial by fire" is a process of intense heat, the burning off of chaff, and the purging of dross from metal ores in the process of refining them with intense heat:

> His winnowing fork is in his hand, to clear his threshing floor and to gather the wheat into his granary; but the chaff he will burn with unquenchable fire. (Luke 3:17)

And:

> See, I am sending my messenger to prepare the way before me, and the Lord whom you seek will suddenly come to his temple. The messenger of the covenant in whom you delight—indeed, he is coming, says the Lord of hosts. But who can endure the day of his coming, and who can stand when he appears? For he is like a refiner's fire and like fullers' soap; he will sit as a refiner and purifier of silver, and he will purify the descendants of Levi and refine them like gold and silver, until they present offerings to the Lord in righteousness. (Malachi 3:1-3)

This cleansing of the heart in the fire of divine love does not happen without the burning off of all our selfish and greedy thoughts and desires in the heated crucible of hard life experience.

As those selfish and greedy thoughts of ours force their way out into harsh words and wrong actions, the impure parts of ourselves are incinerated by "burning coals being heaped upon us" (see [Proverbs 25:21-22; Romans 12:19-21](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Proverbs%2025%3A21-22%3B%20Romans%2012%3A19-21&version=NRSV)), meaning the knowledge and awareness of our own selfishness and greed, and the painful experience of the terribly destructive words and actions that they lead us to say and do.

As we experience these things, the evil desires of our hearts are purged from us, until we no longer have any desire to say and do those evil and destructive things, and take no pleasure in them whatever, but find them horrifying and disgusting.

This is the "baptism with fire" with which Jesus will baptize us if we follow him to the end, fighting the good fight, finishing the race, and keeping the faith ([2 Timothy 4:7](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=2%20Timothy%204:7)).

### Summary

As we go through this full process of being born again by being baptized with water, the Holy Spirit, and fire, Jesus Christ cleanses our actions, our thoughts, and our desires. In other words, he cleanses us completely, from head to toe and from the outside in.

This process continues throughout our lifetime here on earth. And since even "the heavens are not clean in God's sight" (Job 15:15), we continue to be purified and perfected in heaven to all eternity.

The compact answer to the question, then, covering all three forms of baptism, is this:

1. Baptism with *water* is the cleansing of our outward speech and behavior from evil actions and lies.
2. Baptism with *the Holy Spirit* is the cleansing of our mind and spirit from falsity and error.
3. Baptism with *fire* is the cleansing of our heart from evil impulses and desires, and from the pleasure we used to derive from them.

Answer (score 2):

> 16 John answered, saying unto them all, I indeed baptize you with water; but there cometh he that is mightier than I, the latchet of whose shoes I am not worthy to unloose: he shall baptize you in the Holy Spirit and in fire:
>
> 17 whose fan is in his hand, thoroughly to cleanse his threshing-floor, and to gather the wheat into his garner; but the chaff he will burn up with unquenchable fire.

According to the context in “fire” in 3:16 and 17 is not the fire in Acts 2:3, which is related to the Holy Spirit.

> 3 And there appeared unto them tongues parting asunder, like as of fire; and it sat upon each one of them.

Also, the same incident can be seen in Matthew 3:10 and 11. John the Baptist said:

> 10 And even now the axe lieth at the root of the trees: every tree therefore that bringeth not forth good fruit is hewn down, and cast into the fire.
>
> 11 I indeed baptize you in water unto repentance: but he that cometh after me is mightier than I, whose shoes I am not worthy to bear: he shall baptize you in the Holy Spirit and in fire:

These verses mention fire twice. It is not logical to say that the first time fire is mentioned it is negative, but the second time the same word is used it is positive. Therefore, baptism in fire does not have a positive meaning; it is not related to the baptism in the Holy Spirit.

Rather, it is the fire in the lake of fire (Rev. 20:15).

Matthew Henry:

> Probably this refers to the destruction of Jerusalem by the Romans, which was not, as other judgments had been, like the lopping off of the branches, or cutting down of the body of the tree, leaving the root to bud again, but it would be the total, final, and irrecoverable extirpation of that people, in which all those should perish that continued impenitent. Now God would make a full end, wrath was coming on them to the utmost.

Commentary Critical and Explanatory on the Whole Bible (1871)

> The "fire," which in another verse is called "unquenchable," can be no other than that future "torment" of the impenitent whose "smoke ascendeth up for ever and ever," and which by the Judge Himself is styled "everlasting punishment" ( Matthew 25:46 ).
>   Verse 12 continues:
>
> Whose winnowing fan is in His hand. And He will thoroughly cleanse His threshing floor and will gather His wheat into His barn, but the chaff He will burn up with unquenchable fire.

If a person is wheat, Christ will baptize him with the Holy Spirit, and he will have life. However, if he is chaff, He will baptize him with fire; that is, He will put him into the lake of fire.

Here, it means that if the people will truly repent and believe in the Lord Jesus, the Lord will baptize them in the Holy Spirit so that they may have eternal life. Otherwise, the Lord will baptize them in fire, putting them into the lake of fire for eternal punishment. John’s baptism was only for repentance, to usher people to faith in the Lord. The Lord’s baptism is either for eternal life in the Holy Spirit or for eternal perdition in fire.

So, the Pharisees and Sadducees, came to John the Baptist in a pretentious way. It is as if John said, “*If you do not bear fruit, you will be cut down and cast into the fire. You may fool me because I come only to baptize you with water, but you cannot fool Him. When He comes, He will baptize with the Holy Spirit and with fire. He will clear up His threshing floor. If you are the real ones, He will baptize you with the Holy Spirit for life. If you are the false ones, He will put you into the fire*.”

Lastly, there are three kinds of baptisms referred in the Bible: the baptism in water, the baptism in the Holy Spirit, and the baptism in fire. The baptism in water is for repentance, the baptism in the Holy Spirit is for life, and the baptism in fire is for perdition.

Comment: Interesting take on this. Your argument from context makes sense. In English, it would read better with "or fire" if they are opposed. Can you add references? This might make a good hermeneutics question.

Comment: Yes. This is interesting.. another baptism 'by fire'?

Comment: Interesting isn't it? Though it is a minor point. 2 Thess. 1:7-8 do shows "...Jesus is revealed from heaven with his mighty angels [1:8] in flaming fire, inflicting vengeance on those who do not know God and on those who do not obey the gospel of our Lord Jesus". The Lord’s baptism in the Holy Spirit began the kingdom of the heavens, bringing His believers into the kingdom of the heavens, whereas His baptism in fire will terminate the kingdom of the heavens, putting the unbelievers into the lake of fire and will conclude this age.

Comment: I do not believe that the baptism of fire is related to the lake of fire. Rather I believe it is connected with 1Co 3:12-15:  12If anyone builds on this foundation using gold, silver, costly stones, wood, hay or straw, 13their work will be shown for what it is, because the Day will bring it to light. It will be revealed with fire, and the fire will test the quality of each person’s work. 14If what has been built survives, the builder will receive a reward. 15If it is burned up, the builder will suffer loss but yet will be saved—even though only as one escaping through the flames.

Comment: in addition, fire is many times in the bible connected with cleansing (in a way that is true also in Luk 3:17. I believe that the baptism of fire refers to our maturing and ongoing salvation as we become more and more like him, burning away what is our old nature.

Comment: Hey Ralph, I respond to one other question, which is related to your comment and briefly address the matter at http://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/33671/if-we-are-saved-by-grace-then-why-are-we-getting-judged/40665#40665 . I do agree that we need to experience the Spirit's transformation to mature in the divine life. Otherwise, we will be disciplined when the Lord returns as in "saved as through fire" or "cast into outer darkness". Just not in this context of the question above and the verses.

Comment: @ Ralph- Good point.

Comment: Eh? Why the downvote?

Answer (score 1):

The Bible says that Jesus will baptize the Holy Spirit and **with fire** (Matthew 3:11; Mark 1:8; Luke 3:16; John 1:33)

The English word “baptism” came from the Greek word “baptisma” (to dip).This word has more than one meaning.

In Biblical contexts, it means “to identify with” (union with someone) and “to be washed with” (cleansing) whether literally or figuratively.

Therefore, to  be baptized with fire means to be washed or cleansed with fire i.e. God himself.

> Deuteronomy 4:24 (ESV)
>
> For **the LORD your God is a consuming fire**, a jealous God.
>
> Hebrews 12:29 (ESV)
>
> for **our God is a consuming fire.**

God himself is "fire" that devours or destroys sin and its payment which is death (Romans 6:23).

God will destroy death through the Holy Spirit by the resurrection (1 Corinthians 15:55-57;2 Timothy 1:10).Indeed, no one can separate us from the love of God - not even death (Romans 8:28).

> Romans 8:11 (ESV)
>
> If the Spirit of him who raised Jesus from the dead dwells in you, he
>   who raised Christ Jesus from the dead **will also give life to your
>   mortal bodies through his Spirit who dwells in you.**

NOTE

http://biblehub.com/greek/908.htm

Answer (score 1):

Fire does in fact burn up the chaff (wicked); but, fire also PURIFIES 
those vessels of honor (of gold and silver) for His Holy purposes.
I've been meditating on this for a couple hours now, and believe Yahweh provided this Scripture verse as confirmation that our understanding of 
His Holy Fire (of Love) is proper.

> The Purifier - “Behold, I am going to send My messenger, and he will 
>   prepare and clear the way before Me. And the Lord [the Messiah], 
>   whom you seek, will suddenly come to His temple; 
>   the Messenger of the covenant, in whom you delight, behold, 
>   He is coming,” says the Lord of hosts.
>   But who can endure the day of His coming? And who can stand when 
>   He appears? For He is like a refiner’s fire and like launderer’s soap 
>   [which removes impurities and uncleanness]. He will sit as a refiner 
>   and purifier of silver, and He will purify the sons of Levi [the priests], and refine them like gold and silver, so that they may present to the Lord [grain] offerings in righteousness. Then the offering of Judah and Jerusalem will be pleasing to the Lord as in the days of old and as in ancient years." 
>   (Malachi 3:1-4 AMP)

Comment: Welcome! Thanks for contributing.  Unfortunately, the question you've answered is not one that is good for our format, since it invites answers from many different perspectives.  As a result, it has been closed. I hope you'll take a minute to take the [tour] and learn [how this site is different from others](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/a/1809/21576).

Comment: Very good answer. Do not be intimitated by those who do not understand spiritual things, but go after their own intellect and reputation. Luke 12:49-51 has also the answer to this question. And of course Mat 3:11-12. Water & Holy Spirit are Present Baptism, Fire is Future Baptism.